# NoSuchMethodError - CDI fireAsync

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, completable-future

I am trying to use the new fireAsync Method which comes with CDI 2. I am running on a Wildfly 10.1.0.
I always get an error by calling the fireAsnyc() Method:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException
    Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.enterprise.event.Event.fireAsync(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/util/concurrent/CompletionStage;
```

This is my code:

```
@Inject Event<Customer > customerEvent ;

public String save() {
    Customer customer = new Customer("Max", "Smith");
    customerEvent.fireAsync(customer);
    return "something";
}
```

And my pom.xml:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wildfly 10.1 is using Java EE 7 which ships CDI 1.2/Weld 2.3.  You can upgrade it to CDI 2, there's a patch available if you look at [the weld blog](http://weld.cdi-spec.org/news/2017/05/15/weld-300Final/)